# Java - Random Team with Numbers from list

Tags: java, arrays, list, random, numbers

I am Beginner in java
I want to create a random team with numbers

I'm thinking of splitting this random list into 3 teams, what should I do?
because one team only has 2 members

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
public class RandomTeam {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
  }
}
```

Output

```
[3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 5, 0, 1]
```

how to splitting this random list into 3 teams ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: how to splitting this random list into 3 teams ?

Comment: Put the first three elements into team 1 (how are you storing it?), put the next three into team 2 and the last two elements into team 3.

Comment: You have 8 IDs of people in your array and you'd like to generate 3 teams with two members. What is the problem? There will be 2 people left that won't be a member of a team.

Comment: Yes i think like that, but i don't know how to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));` add the following code:

```
int teams = 3;
int teamSize = 2;
if (arr.length >= teams * teamSize) // check if array contains enough IDs
{
    for (int i = 0; (i < arr.length) && (i < teams * teamSize); i += teamSize) {
        System.out.println("Team: " + i/teamSize+1); // print team number
        for (int j = 0; j < teamSize; j++)           // get all team members
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i+j]);            // print ID of team member of team
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of printing the information to console, you could do something else with it. For example generating a team-object. In this case you would have to built a team-class first.

Comment: @Gu1Ldr4n I have found some minor errors (for example the team number was wrong) in my solution and fixed that just now.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide teams by 2 people like the following code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RandomTeam {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] = new int[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = i;
    }
    int numberOfTeams = 3;
    int sizeOfTeam = 2;
    int newTeam[] = new int[2];
    if (arr.length >= (numberOfTeams * sizeOfTeam)){
      for (int i = 0; i < (numberOfTeams*sizeOfTeam); i+=sizeOfTeam) {

        newTeam[0] = arr[i];
        newTeam[1] = arr[i+1];
        Printing((i+1), newTeam);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void Printing(int id, int arr[]) {
    System.out.println("Team{" +
            "id = " + id +
            ", members = " + Arrays.toString(arr) +
            '}');
  }
}
```

when every iteration of the loop, newTeam[] will be replaced by the new team, if you need to create object for every team, then you need to create separate class according to your needs.

Hope, this helps you.